# What is the word when someone go beyond the limit of a mobile phone subscription

Tags: word-usage, word-request

I was looking for a way to call the fact when someone for instance call too much or use too much data and go beyond the limit, we can say:

> "He did a ......"

But I'm looking for this particular word, wich mean the user will pay more than the montly fee.

**edit: the context is: Someone call a foreign country but without a international mobile phone subscription**

Answer (score 2):

**To exceed, To run out of, to go over your limit.**

> You've **exceeded** your data usage this month, if you continue to use
>   more you'll have to pay extra.
>
> You will **run out of** (exceed) your data limit if you keep watching
>   movies all the time.
>
> You will **go over the limit** if you keep downloading games on your
>   phone.
>
> Quick tip, You can also tell someone that they might ***"use up"***
>   all their data if they are constantly using it.

Comment: Thanks for you reply, I updated my request adding the context.

Answer (score 1):

Particularly related to cell phone plans, there is the concept of ["overage charges"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cellphone_overage_charges) which are the fees a customer incurs when they exceed the limits of their plan.